# Samsung Galaxy Tab and Screen Density

Tags: android, galaxy-tab, android-screen-support

As you know Samsung Galaxy Tab's (7.4") screen resolution is 1200x600 and dpi is 160 normally, but Samsung reports its density 240 dpi.

So, i created hdpi graphics for galaxy tab and put them in `drawable-hdpi` folder.

But i noticed that after install custom ICS rom to Galaxy Tab, galaxy tab starts to report its density 160 dpi. So it show mdpi graphics.

I wonder could i do something in my application to handle this special situation; because i know i replace `drawable-mpdi` graphics with `drawable-hdpi` graphics, lots of device will have problems with app, this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is only for the situation explained above, you can use the "Platform Version" qualifier. (Refer to [Providing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html))

`drawable-v14` for ICS and accordingly for other versions. You can also use `drawable-hdpi-v14` for fine grained control.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are talking about the GT-P1000, and it is the only exception to have HDPI density instead of MDPI for that size. I use `drawable-large-HDPI` for it next to a `drawable-large-MDPI` folder for all other similar sized tabs and thus have different resources for both.